# How to pass value from vue.js file to another html file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

the value of the "**symbol**" attribute in the widget must be dynamic depending on the choice of the currency pair in the list, in the vue.js file the value of the currency pair from the list is written to the "**symbol**" variable and I need to transfer the value of this variable from the vue file to normal html in order to use it later this is the value in the html file script
Vue.js file:

```
    <select v-model="currSymbol" @change="event => socket.emit('symbol:change', {symbol: currSymbol, interval: currInterval})">
    <option v-for="pair in pairs">
      {{ pair.symbol }}
    </option>
```

HTML file:

```
 <div id="app">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    new TradingView.widget(
    {
      "width": 1000,
      "symbol": "{{ symbol }}",
      "interval": "D",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "light",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "enable_publishing": false,
      "allow_symbol_change": true,
      "container_id": "tradingview_02e7f"
    }
    );
  </script>
```

I don't know how to accomplish this task.

Comment: you build a spa? Do you want persitent data or if you refresh the page you will start with a default value for example.

Comment: Why do you want to work inside your index.html? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Because the code came from another developer, and I don't imagine how you can integrate this widget into the vue file so that it works correctly, just pass the value to another file at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 new components

One of them is wrapper/ For example:

```
<template>
<div>
   <currency-select @select='setCurrency'/>
   <trading-view :currency='currency'/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
...
data() {
   return {
     currency: null,
   }
},
methods: {
  setCurrency(e) {
     this.currency = e
  },
},
...
</script>
```

trading-view component is:

```
<template>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    </div>
 </template>

<script>
...
props: {
   currency: {
     
   }
},
watch: {
  currency: {
     handler(e) {
        this.buildTradingView()
     }
  }
},
methods:{
   buildTradingView() {
     new TradingView.widget(
    {
      "width": 1000,
      "symbol": this.currency,
      "interval": "D",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "light",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "enable_publishing": false,
      "allow_symbol_change": true,
      "container_id": "tradingview_02e7f"
    }
    );
   },
}
    
  </script>
```

Comment: the first part goes to vue and the second goes to html ?

Comment: no. is new 2 vue components.

Comment: In your html pass this code:
`<div id="app">
<component-first/>
 </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>`